# Configuring Web Server in Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, network-programming, google-compute-engine

I have a dash application in a compute engine instance that I'm looking to view in my browser. HTTP and HTTPS traffic is enabled and the instance has a static IP address. The apache server works and when I first ran an application, the default index page located at `/var/www/html` showed up at the browser address `http://EXTENAL_IP_OF_VM_INSTANCE`

From what I've seen elsewhere, web application files tend to be stored in the `/var/www` directory and the `index.html` file is present as the default page. However I have a single `app.py` file that I want to run which is located in the `/home/user` directory, so not in any particular web directory.

I run the app by entering `python3 app.py` and it does run:

- Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

However, going to the instance's external IP address (34.89.0.xx) in my browser doesn't show the app, instead it shows text from an old 'hello world' application I made previously, that I thought I had deleted but is still showing up.

Part of the server configuration file apache2.conf is below:

[image]

The `sites-available` folder contains two files, `000-default.conf` and `default-ssl.conf`, both with `/var/www/html` as the DocumentRoot. `000-default.conf` is also in the `sites-available` folder, and is the only file there.

I tried changing the DocumentRoot in these files to `/home/user` where the app.py file is which didn't work, then I tried moving the file to the web directory `/var/www` which didn't work either.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this so that I can see my application in the browser?

Comment: Please update your question with configuration of web server. You can access IP `127.0.0.1` **only** from your VM or PC that you're using to run application. You're not able to reach  `127.0.0.1` via network.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I've updated the question with what I know, thanks for the response.

Comment: There's nothing about your application and Python. Does your application have any configuration flags to set IP address?  Does your application publicly available?

Comment: It's a straightforward dash application in a single app.py file. I've tried changing the host IP address in the server clause which was 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 and also to the VM's external static IP address. It's not public, I'm only trying to see it myself when I run the file.

Comment: You should use inernal IP of your VM in configuration of your application, and check service on external IP via browser.